# Emacs artist-mode (no gui)

Tags: emacs

I use emacs for only few days. Now I want to use emacs to draw ascii picture, I search that artist-mode can do it.  But I don't know how to use this mode in no gui environment.

Comment: Have you tried `M-x describe-mode` (or `<f1> m`) when in `artist-mode`?

Comment: some artist-mode command I know,  Eg, C-c C-a P is poly-line,   when I  input this command,  emacs status line change to "Picture:right Artist/s-poly Server". But I don't know how to make a ploy line

Comment: linux x-window, I can use mouse to draw. But I often work use ssh to server to work, it's no gui.

Comment: Check out docstring of `artist-mode`, where it says "Drawing with keys".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To draw a poly line, `C-c C-a P` to enter poly-line mode, `RET` (`artist-key-set-point`) to start the line, move point with normal movement commands, then hit `RET` again to end the segment and start a new one, `C-u RET` for the final segment.

From `artist-mode` docstring:

```
Drawing with keys

 RET        Does one of the following:
        For lines/rectangles/squares: sets the first/second endpoint
        For poly-lines: sets a point (use C-u RET to set last point)
        When erase characters: toggles erasing
        When cutting/copying: Sets first/last endpoint of rect/square
        When pasting: Pastes

 C-c C-a C-o    Selects what to draw

 Move around with C-n, C-p, C-f and C-b.

 C-c C-a C-f    Sets the character to use when filling
 C-c C-a C-l    Sets the character to use when drawing
 C-c C-a C-e    Sets the character to use when erasing
 C-c C-a C-r    Toggles rubber-banding
 C-c C-a C-t    Toggles trimming of line-endings
 C-c C-a C-s    Toggles borders on drawn shapes


Arrows

 <      Sets/unsets an arrow at the beginning
        of the line/poly-line

 >      Sets/unsets an arrow at the end
        of the line/poly-line
```

Answer (score 2):

I find a way to get artist-mode work with mouse when ssh to server.

step:
1.artist-mode
2.xterm-mouse-mode  (confirm your emacs open this mode)
3.some draw command , then draw with your mouse

Any one know how can just use keyboard without mouse can tell me.